# Loading PHP includes in an AJAX called file

Tags: php, html, jquery

I need help getting an ajax function to work properly. I have a page that does a simulated search of a person's zip code. It shows a Google map of their location and an ajax loader.gif. After a 3000 MS timeout, the ajax function is called to load more content in a `<div id="content"></div>`

The problem I am having is that the content that is loaded in the div doesn't seems to be getting any of the CSS styles I need and a few php includes. If I load the page that is called via the ajax function directly in the browser, everything displays fine. But when loaded in the ajax, I am missing the CSS and the PHP includes. Need someone ASAP to help me figure this out! Please respond.

Here's my code:

```
    <?php 
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/inc/tokens.php');
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en" xml:lang="en">

    <!--head code-->       
    <head>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/v1.css" />
    <style type="text/css">

    #quotebtn {
    position:relative;
    margin: 5px 0 1px 0;
    left:45px;
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    height:50px;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: none;
    }

    #form
    {
    margin: 100px;
    }
    </style>

    <!--start scripts-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">

    function ajax_request() {
    setTimeout('load_results()', 3000);
    }

    function load_results(url) {
    $('#content').hide('fast');
    /*$('#content').fadeIn('normal');*/
    $('#content').slideDown('fast', function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
    $('#content').load('page2.php #content', "",
    function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    if(textStatus == 'error') {
    $('#content').html('<p>There was an error making the AJAX request</p>');
    }
    }
    );

    }
    </script>

    </head>  

    <body onload="ajax_request();">

    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="page2.php">welcome</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!--form-->
    <div id="form">
    <div id="top"><img src="<?php echo $imgpath;?>/step1_boxtop.png" width="365px" height="100px" border="0" /></div>

    <!--content-->
    <div id="content">

    <div id="page2text_1"><?php echo $form_text1;?></div>
    <div id="loader"><img src="<?php echo $imgpath;?>/ajax-loader.gif" width="128px" height="15px" border="0" /></div>

    <div id="gmaps">
    <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/offer/v1/gmap.php');?>
    </div>

    <div id="page2text_2"><?php echo $form_text2;?></div>

    </div>
    <!--content-->

    </div>
    <!--form-->

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is the code for page1, that calls page2.php via Ajax. I will also post page2.php's content.

Comment: it is hard to give an answer without seeing page2.php's content

Comment: Here are the pages: 
1) http://dev.autoquotefinders.com/ajax/page2.php
loads the ajax function after 3000ms. but as you can see the css and the facebook functions don't load.

here's what is should look like when called:
http://dev.autoquotefinders.com/ajax/formcode_page2b.php

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you will have better luck with .ajax() instead:

Replace:

```
$('#content').load('page2.php #content', "",
function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
if(textStatus == 'error') {
$('#content').html('<p>There was an error making the AJAX request</p>');
}
}
);
```

With:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({ type: 'POST', cache: false, url: 'page2.php', data: {id: 'somedata'}, 
    success: function(data) {
        $('#content').html(data.find('#content').html());
    }
})
.error(function() {
    $('#content').html('<p>There was an error making the AJAX request</p>');
});
```

Comment: I just made this screencast to hire some live help. perhaps this will explain the problem better. please help. I'll try the ajax code above in the mean time.

http://www.screencast.com/t/fpzg9tafNrV2

Comment: Here is my javascript. can  you edit so that I can paste it into my code and try. Im not to sure what to do with the code above..

Comment: Hmm, nope. it now loads a second form on top of the other. http://dev.autoquotefinders.com/ajax/page2.php

should 'somedata' be edited to somethign?

Comment: is there some limitation with using php includes within the content of a file called in ajax?

Comment: No you are very close to having this work. I updated my answer again.

Comment: hmm that's still not working. it just refreshes the page now with the same content. you can use the posted link to see the code.

Comment: it sounds like no you are seeing a cached version of the ajax response. I updated the answer again to set 'cache' to false.

Comment: If you are still seeing a cached version, you will need to randomize the 'page2.php' url to trick the browser..  so that it is like, 'page2.php?rand=5' where '5' could be any random number..  good luck!

Comment: are you available to chat via IM or Skype? would greatly be appreciated. still just reloading the current page. thx

Comment: no luck on my end. that's why im "PHP Noob". any more ideas? Should this be an easy fix?

Comment: i just checked your page and it seems to be working. did you manage to fix it?

Comment: yea, i hired someone on fiverr to help me. seems i can't use php includes in teh ajax because the javascript inside thenm isnt parsed. i had to use iframes, and it work.

Comment: but...i still have a few more issues i need help with an id be more than happy to pay someone to login a fix em. would u be able to help? i can make a quick video of the remaining issues if u have time.

Comment: sorry, i'm not a php developer!